# Use generated ontology inside a method to another method in java

Tags: java, methods, ontology

First I was generated an ontology inside a `method1`. it is successful. Then inside the second method I need to use this generated ontology for another process. I used following code. It gave an  error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException.

Where is the problem? How I need to take generated ontology in `method1` to `method2`?

```
     public class OntologyCreation {

        public static void main (String args[]) {

        //main
        OntologyCreation ont = new OntologyCreation(); 
        OntModel m = null;
        String ontoClass = null;
        ont.method2(ontoClass, m);


        public  void method1(OntModel m) {     //for ontologyCreation
        m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
        -----
        -----
        }


        public ArrayList<String> method2(String ontoClass, OntModel m) {   // 2nd method for use generated ontology to another process
        method1(m);
        m.read("http://localhost/myont/ont.owl");      ????????
        ExtendedIterator<OntClass> classes = ((OntModel) m).listClasses(); 
        ----------
        ----------               
         }
        return xx; 
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `OntModel` more than once with the `OntologyCreation` instance, you could use a field to store the variable:

```
private OntModel m;

public void method1() {
    this.m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
}

public ArrayList<String> method2(String ontoClass) {
    method1();
    this.m.read("http://localhost/myont/ont.owl"); // use field value
```

The alternative is returning the created `OntModel` as described in the other answers.

**Note:** Java is always pass-by-value, which is why the value in the `method2` method remains `null`, see [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change variables outside of a function by assigning to the name of the parameter inside the function. The only thing this does is change the local variable in question. So the assignment to `m` in `method1` sets the local variable `m` correctly, but that does not effect the variable `m` in `method2`.

The solution is to make `method1` return the object and then assigning it to the local variable: `m = method1()`

Answer (score 0):

Return `m` in `method1`:

```
public OntModel method1(OntModel m) {     //for ontologyCreation
    m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
    /*-----*/
    return m;
}
```

And in `method2`, the call should be:

```
m = method1(m);
```

Java passes references by value, meaning `method1` receives an adress of object `m`. However, `m = something` means you change that address value inside `method1`. Outside, it is still the same and still points towards a `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You `m` variable isn't being instantiated before `method2`is called.

Therefore it has the value `null` associated.

Even though you're calling `method1`, that attribution will only be valid on the method's scope.

You ought to do `OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);` before `ont.method2(ontoClass, m);` in order to be able to use `m` on `method2`.